# Keep getting "Param is missing or the value is empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting the error mentioned above, even though my form object matches my controller object (most people who had this problem had mixed their objects up in similar questions). What exactly am I doing wrong here?

My code is below:

```
<!-- The form is here -->  
<%= form_for(@user), url: {action: "/users/signup"}, html: {class: "signup_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= label_tag(:firstname, "Firstname: ") %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
    <%= label_tag(:lastname, "Lastname: ") %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
    <%= label_tag(:username, "Username: ") %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
    <%= label_tag(:email, "Email: ") %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
end

private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :username,
        :email, :password)
    end
end
```

Would really appreciate some help and sorry if I missed something silly here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, success: 'Thanks for signing up!' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end
end
```

**users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name, "First name" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name, "Last name" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email, "Email" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `url: {action: "/users/signup"}` in the form? It is much simpler if you do the following:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user
end
```

**views/users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user), html: {class: "signup_form"} do |f| %>
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb** (add the following)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

If you do it like this, `form_for` will automatically detect whether or not the `@user` object has been saved in the database, and will route the form to the `create` or `update` method respectively.

I general I don't reccommend altering the standard RESTful routes unless absolutley necessary. A user is not likely going to look at `yoursite.com/users/new` in the URL and be upset or confused.